# Blender 2.7 Python Null result without error in PyObject_Call

Tags: python, python-2.7, blender

I have a very simple script in Blender 2.7:

    `bpy.ops.object.text_add(location = (params["pos"]["x"], params["pos"]["y"])
    ob=bpy.context.object
    ob.data.body = "my text"`

Nothing happens when I run the script, and the Blender console shows an

> invalid syntax error

on the second line, and

> SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call

It worked fine before, then I changed the line spacing and it throws this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What I see with what you have shown is that the text_add needs a third part for location - x,y,z and a closing bracket. As for changing line spacing, are you sure you didn't alter indenting so that something is now in the wrong scope?